# Pandas: use a timeseries as a mask for selection

Tags: python, pandas, selection

I try to use a mask to make a selection from my groupby object, but I get an error I cant resolve.

First I group by groupid

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('groupid')
```

Then I calculated the STD, min and max from each group to use in my selection masks.

```
df_grouped_std = df_grouped.std()
df_grouped_min = df_grouped.min()
df_grouped_max = df_grouped.max()
```

Then I create two masks on different parameters.

```
s1 = df_grouped_std['distance']<0.05
s2 = (df_grouped_max.speed- df_grouped_min.speed) < 10
```

Finally I combine the masks.

```
sTot = s1&s2
```

This gives the following error/stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-198-b0df7aa8bb76>", line 1, in <module>
    selection = df_grouped[sTot.values]

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 3155, in __getitem__
    % str(bad_keys)[1:-1])

KeyError: 'Columns not found: False, True'
```

Afterwards I'd like to use the mask to select.

```
selection = df_grouped[sTot]
```

I see that s1,s2 and Stot are time-series and maybe that is why I cant use them to select, but I cant figure out why that would be. What am I missing here?

Data example:

```
print(s1.head())
print(s2.head())
print(sTot.head())

groupid
941          True
942          True
1721         True
1722         True
2201         True
Name: distance, dtype: bool

groupid
941           True
942           True
1721         False
1722          True
2201         False
Name: speed, dtype: bool

groupid
941           True
942           True
1721         False
1722          True
2201         False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: can you output the head of s1 and s2? Do `print(s1.head())` and `print(s2.head())` and copy and paste the output here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
print (df.groupby('groupID')
         .filter(lambda x: (x.distance.std() < 0.05) & 
                           ((x.speed.max()- x.speed.min()) < 10)))
```

Sample (changed `0.05` to `1`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'groupID':[1,1,3,3],
                   'speed':[4,5,6,1],
                   'distance':[1,2,3,1]})

print (df)
   distance  groupID  speed
0         1        1      4
1         2        1      5
2         3        3      6
3         1        3      1

print (df.groupby('groupID')
         .filter(lambda x: (x.distance.std() < 1) & 
                           ((x.speed.max()- x.speed.min()) < 10)))

   distance  groupID  speed
0         1        1      4
1         2        1      5
```

Comment: Works like a charm and is much cleaner than the approach I figured out.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want for the result? Do you want all entries in which groups (where the conditions hold), or just the aggregated information for the groups?

I think @jezrael 's solution is good if you want all the entries. Btw, you may find .get_group() useful.

You can do the following:

```
for k, v in sTot.iteritems():
    if v == True:
        print df_grouped.get_group(k)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works too. However what I want is all the entries and as you mentioned, @jezraels solution is great for that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another solution. After the code in the question:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('groupid')

df_grouped_std = df_grouped.std()
df_grouped_min = df_grouped.min()
df_grouped_max = df_grouped.max()

s1 = df_grouped_std['distance']<0.05
s2 = (df_grouped_max.speed- df_grouped_min.speed) < 10
```

I do apply all the selections on the df_grouped_std

```
sTot2 = df_grouped_std[s1][s2][s3][s4][s5]
```

Then I use the index values of the selected columns, and select those from the original (ungrouped) dataframe. Finally I group again, because I need the groups.

```
selection = sTot2.index.get_level_values(0)
selected_groups = df[df.ROL_IDENT.isin(selection)].groupby('ROL_IDENT')
```

Though this works, I'd prefer @jezraels approach since I think it is much cleaner.